# Raspberry pi 3 B connection with wireless IP camera through RTSP (Wifi)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, video-capture, opencv3.0, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm using python=3.5 and OpenCV 3.1.4 to establish a connection with my IP camera via RTSP protocol using wifi on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Here's my code

```py
import cv2
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
vs = WebcamVideoStream(src="rtsp://192.168.1.4").start()
while 1:
    frame = vs.read()
    cv2.imshow("video",frame)
    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
vs.release()
```

Which raises the error:

```
    OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/pi/opencv-3.4.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 356
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_cam.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("video",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/pi/opencv-3.4.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

From the error it's clear that frames are not being captured from the supplied connection which means connection is not properly established. This code was working perfectly fine when I ran it on ubuntu. When I ran it on raspberry pi rasbian stretch kernel version 4.14 I get this error.

Can anyone guide me through how can I read and process frames from IP camera in python and openCV connected through WiFi?